# Perl dictionary?

Tags: perl, dictionary

I am new to perl and reading a script, I have not come across these style of curly brackets, in python these are generally a dictionary what is it in this case?

```
$connstrings{"V2"}{"Production"} = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;";
$connstrings{"V2"}{"Production"} .= "Network Library=DBMSSOCN;";
$connstrings{"V2"}{"Production"} .= "Data"
$connstrings{"V2"}{"Production"} .= "Persist Security Info=True;";
$connstrings{"V2"}{"Production"} .= "User ID=sffsupply_build;";
$connstrings{"V2"}{"Production"} .= "Initial Catalog=dir_sffsupply;";
```

Comment: This is a multi-dimensional hash reference that appends (via `.=`) a string to the entry in `$connstrings{"V2"}{"Production"}`.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that a good tutorial can help you with. For starters, take a look at [perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Perl-variable-types) and [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Comment: They're, uh, a dictionary. Perl calls them "hashes"

Comment: thanks always learning here.  Don't get the down votes but whatever.

Comment: I expect you're getting downvotes because hashes are a very basic Perl concept and people don't understand why you wouldn't read a simple Perl tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

In that context, they are how you specify the name of a key on a hash when fetching the value of that key.

Hashes are described in [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html).

```
my %example = ( foo => "bar", one => "two" );
if ($example{"foo"} eq "bar") {
    print 1;
}
```